# How can I convert this date-format in a format accepted by lubridate?

Tags: r, excel, datetime, lubridate

I have imported data in R from an Excel sheet with package readxl.

The sheet contains a column with dates. These dates behave like dates in Excel (I can change the date formatting in Excel).

Directly after importing in R with readxl the format is this:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  `datum`         
  <dttm>             
1 2010-01-20 21:00:00
```

My goal is to use the lubridate function days_in_month on the imported dates.

```
lubridate::days_in_month(df[2,1])
```

Although using this function gives this error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”
```

I did serveral test to identify the format:

```
is.Date(df[2,1])
is.POSIXt(df[2,1])
is.instant(df[2,1])
```

All give result FALSE.

If I print one date I receive this result:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  `datum`         
  <dttm>             
1 2010-01-20 21:00:00
```

I have tried several conversions:

```
df$datum <- as.Date(df$datum, origin = "1899-12-30")
df$datum <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(df$datum, 'GMT'))
df$datum <- as.Date(df$datum, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Although the results of the tests above after conversion are all FALSE.

If I do the first conversion as.Date(df$datum, origin = "1899-12-30").
After this the outcome of print is:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  `datum`
  <date>    
1 2010-01-20


df$datum + 60 gives:
1 2010-03-21
```

So it seems it is behaving as a date since I can add 60.

Although all the test give FALSE and days_in_month from lubridate still gives the error above.

How can I convert the date into a correct format which lubridate can process?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `"2010-01-20 21:00:00"` is not a date, it's a date-time. If you want it to be a `Date`, I suggest you either (1) convert to time then date, with `as.Date(as.POSIXct(...))`; or (2) truncate the string and convert, something like `as.Date(gsub(" .*", "", df$datum))` or `as.Date(substr(df$datum, 1, 10))`.

Comment: @ r2evans Thanks, I will try this, although I did several conversions with as.Date as I mentioned above.

Comment: More thoughts (as I caffeinate): your sample of `df$datum` above is already `POSIXt`, so `as.Date` just works. And it seems like the problem you're having is with code and data that we do not have. Can you provide the output from `dput(head(df$datum))` and the code you're using that is generating the error? I see no calls to `lubridate::` in your code.

Comment: @ r2evans. Thanks! I have added the code in the question above.  The output from dput(head(df$datum)) is : structure(list(`datum` = structure(14629, class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: as.Date(substr(df$datum, 1, 10)) gives : Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: Again, please, `dput(head(df$datum))` *before `as.Date` or `as.POSIXt`), you've never shown raw data.

Comment: @ r2evans I have added an example of the raw data (directly after import in R) to my question. Please see above.

Comment: That sample shows that the data is already a `POSIXt` (the `dttm` column-class), in which case `as.Date(datum)` should work without additional arguments. As an example, `lubridate::days_in_month(as.Date(Sys.time()))` works for me (where `Sys.time()` returns a `POSIXct` object, which should be what is in your `dttm`-class column).

Comment: @ r2evans your example with Sys.time works for me too. My example above gives Error in as.Date.default(df1[2, 1]) :   do not know how to convert 'dagen[2, 1]' to class “Date”. A difference is that my Sys.time gives "2020-04-16 20:15:57 CEST" and the imported Excel gives 2010-01-20 21:00:00 , no CEST and no " ".

Comment: If I do str(df) directly after import from Excel, it says: POSIXct, format: "2010-01-01 13:25:00" (for the first row). So this format should be correct.

Comment: Your question uses `df`, but this last comment references `df1` and `dagen`, is that a missed commend-edit? Also, is there a reason you refer to `df$datum` in some places and `df[2,1]` in others? Your sample data shows 1 row, 1 column, so `[2,1]` is wrong anyway. Perhaps that's your problem ...

Comment: @ r2evans The reason is that I try to keep a simple name for df here and a short column name different than in my original dataframe. That is not the problem. I do the right tests in R. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being bitten by the differences in `[` between `data.frame` and `tbl_df`. Reading your file (present in the comments), I ultimately see:

```r
df <- readxl::read_excel("example dates.xlsx")
df
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   datum               datum2             
#   <dttm>              <dttm>             
# 1 2010-01-01 13:25:00 2010-12-22 23:53:40
# 2 2010-01-23 13:30:00 2011-01-07 23:09:10
# 3 2010-02-16 21:45:00 2011-03-19 01:00:52

# for everybody else
df <- structure(list(datum = structure(c(1262352300, 1264253400, 1266356700), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), datum2 = structure(c(1293062020.704, 1294441750.08, 1300496452.128), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Can we agree that it does not make sense to try to convert a whole frame at once?

```r
as.Date(df)
# Error in as.Date.default(df) : 
#   do not know how to convert 'df' to class "Date"
```

Dumb question. Well, let's see what happens with other variants.

```r
df$datum
# [1] "2010-01-01 13:25:00 UTC" "2010-01-23 13:30:00 UTC" "2010-02-16 21:45:00 UTC"
as.Date(df$datum)
# [1] "2010-01-01" "2010-01-23" "2010-02-16"
```

```r
df[2,1]
# # A tibble: 1 x 1
#   datum              
#   <dttm>             
# 1 2010-01-23 13:30:00
as.Date(df[2,1])
# Error in as.Date.default(df[2, 1]) : 
#   do not know how to convert 'df[2, 1]' to class "Date"
```

With a simple `data.frame`, `[2,1]` will return a scalar, not a frame, so that makes sense in base R:

```r
as.data.frame(df)[2,1]
# [1] "2010-01-23 13:30:00 UTC"
as.Date(as.data.frame(df)[2,1])
# [1] "2010-01-23"
```

So the problem is that `tibble` is forcing you to be explicit in that you want to drop from a frame to a scalar/vector.

This is normally a good thing, frankly. When dealing with a "normal" (non-`tibble`) frame and you want to look at a group of columns, `as.data.frame(df[,1:2])`, R always returns a `data.frame`. Unfortunately, if you define the columns programmatically and it returns a single column, then `[` by default reduces it from a frame to a vector: `as.data.frame(df)[,1]`. You can prevent this auto-coercion with `drop=`, ala `as.data.frame(df[,1,drop=FALSE])`. Many (including myself) consider this to be a mistake: `df[,cols]` should be relied on to always return the same type of object, regardless if it is 20 columns or just 1 column. (I recognize that there are reasons why it does this, and I'm not berating the original R developers.)

So the *problem* causing your error is that `tibble` is requiring you to be explicit when subsetting your `tbl_df` into a single cell. If you want to work on a single cell, use `df$datum[2]` or `df[2,1][[1]]` to force it. If you want to work on a whole column, then `df$datum` . And all of those work directly with `as.Date`, since it knows how to deal with vectors of `POSIXt` (natively) and `numeric`/`integer` (along with `origin=`). Unfortunately, `df[,1]` of a tibble will not return a vector, so `as.Date` does not know what to do with it.

Bottom line:

```r
as.Date(df$datum[2])
# [1] "2010-01-23"
as.Date(df[2,1][[1]])
# [1] "2010-01-23"
as.Date(df$datum)
# [1] "2010-01-01" "2010-01-23" "2010-02-16"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your effort!! This is indeed the solution. Indeed I used MyColumn <- select(df, datum) instead of MyColumn <- df$datum. I thought it is always better to use the tidyverse commands. I had tried to simplify my code before posting to make it easier to read. Although I realize now this can result in important omissions as well. Great you detected the cause. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to stick with `tidyverse`, then you could easily use `... %>% mutate(datum = as.Date(datum))` and all would be fine.

Comment: I am still a newbe in R and I have no preference for any methods, although if I understood correctly tidyverse is well structured and a good basis. Although I keep stucked the most often with issues caused by data-types. It seems very hard to avoid these for some reason.

Comment: R's flexibility in data-types is both a blessing and a curse. Other languages that are less flexible give you fast and immediate feedback (instead of differing outputs), and force you to be explicit (even declarative) in how you treat variables. `tidyverse` does standardize some verbiage and syntax among a set of base R functions that are rather inconsistent at times. On the flip side, if you're dealing with a lot of data (~ 1M or more rows), then `data.table` can be much much faster. For both, I find `magrittr`'s pipe (`%>%`) to really clear up R's paren-fetish.

Comment: I thought R is very strict in data-types, causing these issues. Do you know if Python is more or less flexible than R? What do you mean with R's paren-fetish?

Comment: R is influenced heavily by C and Lisp, the latter is well-known to use parentheses heavily, so much so that without indentation and other coding *styles*, it can be really difficult to see where code lies in the execution path. R can be loose with its silent coercion of some data types, but some functions are intolerant of what they accept.

Comment: Aha, the parentheses! Nice defined: loose with silence coercion and some intolerance what functions accept.